# Specify thread to use for task in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have an application where I have a stream of incoming data.
As each data packet arrives I want to process it on a specific thread to avoid synchronisation issues.  How can I create a thread to run a specific action, then start it with given parameters for each incoming data packet?  Is there a better way to go about this?
i.e. I have this currently:

```
        Task.Run(()=>MainWindow.ChartData(dat[0], vd.airspeed, vd.yaw));
```

But instead of starting a new thread each time, I want each call to happen on the same thread.

Comment: Apply a producer-consumer pattern, where each consumer runs on its own thread?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# threading: calling a function on a different thread in its context and returning results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307824/c-sharp-threading-calling-a-function-on-a-different-thread-in-its-context-and-r)

Comment: call like `MainWindow.ChartData` smells really bad

Answer (score 3):

Create a class that creates a single thread and passes work to this thread. Other classes could push work to this class.

This is what is called a dispatcher. The dispatcher could encapsulate a queue and have a single thread sleep for a while, acquire the lock of the queue, check the queue for items, get a couple of items from the queue, release the lock of the queue, process some items,  and go back to sleep for a while.

The dispatcher would have a method that would acquire the lock of the queue, add a work item and release the lock of the queue. This method would be called by other threads to post work.